# 'imgSrc' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, variables

Consider this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let imageUrlRequest = axios.get(imageEndPointString).then(function (response) {
        console.log('call made')
        let imgSrc = response.data[0].data.children[0].data.url;
        console.log(imgSrc)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        // always executed
      });
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="game__image">
      <h2>IMAGE URL: {imgSrc}</h2>
      <img src={imgSrc} />
    </div>
  );
```

Howcome `imgSrc` is undefined?

I also tried this

```
let imgSrc;

  useEffect(() => {
    let imageUrlRequest = axios.get(imageEndPointString).then(function (response) {
        console.log('call made')
        imgSrc = response.data[0].data.children[0].data.url;
        console.log(imgSrc)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        // always executed
      });
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="game">
      <img src={imgSrc} />
    </div>
  );
```

but the image still won't come through. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript variables that are declared inside a block can be used only in this block (local scope).
Furthermore, in React if you want to change your view based on some value you must use the `setState` function to allow React to know when it should re-render the view.

So in your example you need to do something like this:

```
const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    let imageUrlRequest = axios.get(imageEndPointString).then(function (response) {
        console.log('call made')
        setImgSrc(response.data[0].data.children[0].data.url);
        console.log(imgSrc)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        // always executed
      });   },[]);

  return (
    <div className="game__image">
      <h2>IMAGE URL: {imgSrc}</h2>
      <img src={imgSrc} />
    </div>   );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because on the first render (before the useEffect) you are trying to use the variable `imgSrc` as the image source, so you get an error before the `useEffect` executes. What you can do is using a default value on your return in case `imgSrc` is still undefined at that moment. Something like

```
<img src={imgSrc || "anotherurl.com"} />
```

Just use any placeholder default image url and you should get rid of your problem